# Closures and Loops in Python

Tags: python, closures

Suppose I have the following code

```
callbacks = []
for i in range(10):
    callbacks.append(lambda x: i)
```

all functions in `callbacks` will return the final value of `i`.  How can I create callbacks that return the *current value for i at creation time*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for i in range(10):
  callbacks.append(lambda x = i : x)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
In [113]: callbacks=[]

In [114]: for i in range(10):
    callbacks.append(lambda x=i:x**2)
   .....:     
   .....:     

In [117]: callbacks[0]()
Out[117]: 0

In [118]: callbacks[1]()
Out[118]: 1

In [119]: callbacks[2]()
Out[119]: 4

In [120]: callbacks[4]()
Out[120]: 16
```

Comment: I suppose you meant `lambda x=i: x`?