# Issue calling lambda stored in dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, lambda

I'm currently learning Python and playing with the concepts of dictionaries and lambda functions. I have an issue with the following code:

```
def helloName(name):
    print 'hello %s' % name

myList = ['one', 'two', 'three']
myDict = {}

print '====' * 4

for i in myList:
    myDict[i] = lambda: helloName(i)
    print i + ' : ' +  str(myDict[i])

print '====' * 4

myDict['one']()
print myDict['one']
myDict['two']()
print myDict['two']
myDict['three']()
print myDict['three']

print '====' * 4

for i in myList:
    myDict[i]()
    print i + ' : ' +  str(myDict[i])
```

The output of this script is:

```
================
one : <function <lambda> at 0x0060C330>
two : <function <lambda> at 0x01FB4FB0>
three : <function <lambda> at 0x01FA9570>
================
hello three
<function <lambda> at 0x0060C330>
hello three
<function <lambda> at 0x01FB4FB0>
hello three
<function <lambda> at 0x01FA9570>
================
hello one
one : <function <lambda> at 0x0060C330>
hello two
two : <function <lambda> at 0x01FB4FB0>
hello three
three : <function <lambda> at 0x01FA9570>
```

I don't understant the second block of outputed lines. I expected exactly the same output as the third block of outputed lines.

Could you help me understanding the difference between both outputs and suggest a modification to have twice the same output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of the closure property of Python. To fix this

```
myDict[i] = lambda i=i: helloName(i)
```

This question has been answered already [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233673/lexical-closures-in-python), [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13038779/1903116), [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7546285/1903116), [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12423614/local-variables-in-python-nested-functions) and [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19768456/1903116)

Comment: Thank you, it does indeed solve my issue. Could you point me to some documentation explaining in more details this closure property?

Comment: @Grimmy Please check the questions which I included in my answer :)

Comment: Yep, I was reading it. Thanks again for the info :)

Comment: @Grimmy You are welcome :) I have added few more questions, please go through all of them. This is very common problem :)